# Event when drag starts and ends in jQuery DataTables RowReorder

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am in the middle of implementing [jQuery DataTables RowReorder](http://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) extension and need to make changes in DOM when drag is in-progress, and stop the process when it is completed. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`row-reorder`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/row-reorder) event to detect when rows has been reordered.

```
$('#example').on('row-reorder.dt', function(e, details, edit){   
   for(var i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
      console.log(
         'Node', details[i].node, 
         'moved from', details[i].oldPosition, 
         'to', details[i].newPosition
      );
   }
});
```

To track row dragging events use undocumented events `mousedown.rowReorder` and `ousemove.rowReorder` as shown below.

```
$('#example').on('mousedown.rowReorder touchstart.rowReorder', 'tbody tr td:eq(0)', function(){
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');    
   console.log('Started dragging row', tr);

   $(document).on('mousemove.rowReorder touchmove.rowReorder', function(){
      console.log('Dragging row', tr);
   });
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5da98rk/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Tnx it saved me ^^

Comment: Your fiddle is broken for me

Answer (score 3):

Good question. There is absolutely no documentation on this issue (at the time this is written). The result of investigating the code is :

There is actually triggered an event after a RowReorder-dragdrop, `row-reorder.dt`. This passes 3 arguments I dare to call `dragEvent`, `data` and `nodes`.

- `dragEvent`, basic jQuery UI event
- `data`, an array with the most important information about the row reordering, for each item `oldPosition`, `newPosition` and the `node` itself.
- `nodes`, the DOM nodes / `<tr>` elements involved in the dragdrop-event.

So, an example of usage :

```
$('#example').on('row-reorder.dt', function(dragEvent, data, nodes) {
    alert('row #'+
          data[0].node._DT_RowIndex+
          ' moved from pos '+
          data[0].oldPosition+
          ' to pos '+
          data[0].newPosition+"\n"+
          'row #'+
          data[1].node._DT_RowIndex+
          ' changed position from '+
          data[1].oldPosition+
          ' to '+
          data[1].newPosition          
    );
})
```

[image]

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/**

Comment: Event [`row-reorder`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/row-reorder) is documented [here](http://datatables.net/reference/event/row-reorder). What about `mousemove` event while dragging?

Comment: See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1/) for an example on how to track mouse move event, it is  based on inspecting plug-in source code.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com :$ That was really embarrasing :( I totally looked for this, but apparently Jardines new "design" is hard for me to adopt.  I have looked at your fiddle - tried almost the same myself, one would expect a normal jQuery UI dragstart event etc was triggered, but they are not. I does not work for me, tried with both Chrome and FF using ubuntu 14.04. Nothing in the console.

Comment: It works for me in all latest browsers (Chrome 45, FF 40, IE 11).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, also tried with opera and MacBook Air - your fiddle simply never triggers `mousedown.rowReorder` etc. Where in the [**code**](http://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js) are those events triggered?

Comment: Very strange that it doesn't work for you. Those are regular mouse events `mousedown`, `mousemove`, the code is just using [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names). Search in the [code](http://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js) for `mousedown.rowReorder` and `mousemove.rowReorder`.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - have now tried on an old windows7 laptop too. No messages in the console either. I actually thought that for some reason it would have something to do with platforms / browsers.  It didnt worked out for me then I tried it myself, none of your fiddles works for me. Really, really strange. The only thing I have not tried yet is windows 8 / 10. What are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 / Chrome 45, FF 40, IE 11. Can you please change `console.log` to `alert` and re-run the fiddle?